# expo-av how to play audio with URL

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm working with `expo-av` package in my Expo managed app.

I'm passing a url to an audio file on the internet to `createAsync`, but the audio is not playing. When I use an audio file that lives alongside the source code with `require()`, the audio plays without problem.

```
  const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({uri: url});
  await sound.playAsync();
  await sound.unloadAsync();
```

Is there any specific steps needed for playing audio on the internet?

Comment: Is the audio autoplay? Browsers generally don't allow audio that autoplays.  https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Comment: @ethry I apologize if my post was unclear. But the project is a React Native App, not a web app. Still, if you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it if you could share them with me :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import { Audio } from "expo-av"

const sound = new Audio.Sound()

await sound.loadAsync({
    uri: your_audio_url
})

await sound.playAsync()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour